# Convert each vector in a list of vector to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a list which contains the degree of nodes of a graph as follows:

```
degree <- list()

degree[[4]]<-degree(graph[[4]],v=V(graph[[4]]),mode="all")

> degree[[4]]
62586  4654   353  1883  7241  2680  1369 11942 21516 19922 20777  1137   251  3188 26013  7444 
3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1 
 2927  3439 65369 21737 16897   185 
1     1     1     1     1     1
```

I need to convert each vector in the list of vector (here degree[[4]]) to a matrix. I have tried the following:

```
matrix4 <- matrix(degree[[4]], nrow = length(degree[[4]]))

> matrix4
      [,1]
 [1,]    3
 [2,]    1
 [3,]    1
 [4,]    1
 [5,]    1
 [6,]    1
 [7,]    1
 [8,]    1
 [9,]    1
[10,]    1
[11,]    1
[12,]    1
[13,]    1
[14,]    1
[15,]    1
[16,]    1
[17,]    1
[18,]    1
[19,]    1
[20,]    1
[21,]    1
[22,]    1
```

But I also need the node names in the matrix.

```
> str(degree[[4]])
 Named num [1:22] 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:22] "62586" "4654" "353" "1883" ...

matrix4 <- cbind(degree[[4]]$names,matrix(degree[[4]], nrow = length(degree[[4]])))
```

does not work because degree[[4]]$names gives me an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
matrix4 <- matrix( degree[[4]], 
         nrow = length(degree[[4]]), 
         dimnames=list(names(degree[[4]])) )
```

For example

```
> matrix4 <- matrix(degree[[4]], nrow = length(degree[[4]]), dimnames=list(names(degree[[4]])))
> degree[[4]]<-c(4,3,4,2)
> names(degree[[4]])=c("a","b","cc","ddd")
> degree[[4]]
  a   b  cc ddd 
  4   3   4   2 
> matrix4 <- matrix(degree[[4]], nrow = length(degree[[4]]), dimnames=list(names(degree[[4]])))
> matrix4
    [,1]
a      4
b      3
cc     4
ddd    2
```

Comment: ncol(matrix4) returns 1. I think it should return 2 columns. But   matrix <- cbind(names(degree[[4]]),matrix(degree[[4]], nrow = length(degree[[4]]))) gives me the correct result. Thanks.

Comment: matrix4 in my example has only 1 col. If this works for you the can you please mark the answer so that I can collect my valuable points. Thanks